# Alpha Protocol: Purpose of the computer in the first server node room?

Tags: alpha-protocol

I'm in Taipei right now, doing the "Access Network" goal in the "Trace Warehouse Data Trail" mission.  I'm pretty sure I'm on Hard difficulty.

I'm in the first room where you encounter servers to bug - there's three of them, along with guards and cameras.  If you walk into the northwest alcove of this room (where you find the dossier on Sis), there's a computer which I can hack if I want to, but which has no context message and appears to do nothing after being hacked.

What's it for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hacking that particular computer gives you 25 XP. I suspect that it might be context sensitive, depending on the order in which you tackle the different cities.